# xmlHttp url utf8 charset issue

Tags: ms-access

I've got an application on `access 2010`. The application calls a `webservice` using `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` request object. Some parameters are given using the `url` and can contains specials characters (ê, é, ...). I added a content-type which indicates i want to use `utf8` charset `("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")`.

The issue is that the `webservice` doesn't receive the correct specials characters, it seems the result is encoded as `ASCII`. My Guess is i have to convert string from access to `utf8` before i call the `xmlHttp.open()` method.

I tried many things as `StrConv()` function, many `URLEncode()` found on internet, but it doesn't seems to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the string into a utf8 character set you can use the ADODB.Stream object.

```
Dim adoS as New ADODB.Stream

adoS.Type = adTypeText
adoS.Charset = "utf-8"
adoS.Open
```

You can then use the stream to convert your string.